# When to capitalize titles such as mayor (for the SAT)

Tags: capitalization

Studying for the SAT I came across the practice sentence "By next month, Ms. Jones will be Mayor of Tallahassee for two years."

I know that it should be corrected to "will have been" instead of "will be" but I was confused on why mayor is supposed to be lowercase.

If a person's name is never mentioned is it not a title? Would this also apply to other job titles such as "Director of Communication" or are there special rules governing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Job- no capitalization.

Title before the persons’s name- capitalize. Think like Mayor is replacing “Ms.” or “Mr.”

Used in place of person’s name as a direct address- capitalize.

https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/capitalization/capitalization-of-job-titles.html

> > To summarize the capitalization of job titles, you capitalize the job title when it comes immediately before the name, in a formal context or in direct address. It is not generally capitalized if it comes after the person's name, or if there is a "the" before it.

Same with director.  The link has examples of political jobs, business titles, etc.